# How to tell if internet is down on Macbook

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

When ISP is down, we get limited connection error on Widows (see screenshots) with yellow exclamation mark on wifi toolbar, same thing happens in android. In this way we can tell that, there is some problem with ISP and that's why we don't have internet access.

[image]

Now I am new mac user and want to know how to tell the same, on mac.

P.S : Do note that this information is helpful in troubleshooting internet, for instance if ISP is down there is nothing we can do, but if there is problem in system wifi card or router than we can just restart it and get back internet access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't own a MacBook, but I think this will help you out: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38628/how-to-see-your-current-wi-fi-connection-speed-in-mac-os-x/

"Using Option-Click
As pointed out by anon in the comments, you can simply hold down the Option key while clicking on the menu bar icon for your Airport, and it will show you the extended information in the popup display."